# Any nonabelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've read a [proof](http://crystal.ou.edu/~tprzebin/5363_exam1_sol.pdf) at the end of this document that any nonabelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, but it feels clunky to me.

I want to try the following instead:

Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $6$. By Cauchy's theorem or the Sylow theorems, there is a element of order $2$, let it generate a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. Let $G$ act on the quotient set $G/H$ by conjugation. This induces a homomorphism $G\to S_3$. I want to show it's either injective or surjective to get the isomorphism.

I know $n_3\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $n_3\mid 2$, so $n_3=1$, so there is a unique, normal Sylow $3$-subgroup. Also, $n_2\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, and $n_2\mid 3$, so $n_2=1$ or $3$. However, if $n_2=1$, then I know $G$ would be a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, but then $G\cong C_2\times C_3\cong C_6$, a contradiction since $G$ is nonabelian. So $n_2=3$. Can this info be used to show the homomorphism is either injective or surjective? Thanks.

Comment: You can't talk about the **quotient** $G/H$ unless you know that $H$ is normal; and you have no warrant for asserting that $H$ is normal. And if you try acting on the cosets by conjugation, you will find that it is not well-defined.

Comment: This isn't your question, but the proof I expected to see in your document, and didn't see, is that (by Cauchy's theorem) $G$ has elements $a$ of order 2 and $b$ of order 3. The set $\{1, a, b, ab, b^2, ab^2\}$ is easily seen to exhaust $G$; no two of these can be equal if $a$ and $b$ are to have orders 2 and 3. Since $ba\in G$, we have $ba = a^ib^j$ for some $i\in\{0, 1\}$ and $j\in\{0,1,2\}$. $i=0$ and $j=0$ are easily ruled out. This leaves $ba=ab$ and $ba=ab^2$. The first is abelian. The second is the canonical presentation of $D_6 = S_3$, so we're done.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, so such an approach is not possible? Darn. Thank you.

Comment: @TiffanyHwang: You are just acting on the wrong thing in the wrong way. You can use the *cosets* and left multiplication.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So if the action is left multiplication, then since necessarily $gH=H$ for $g$ in the kernel $K$, so $K\subset H$. But if $K=H$, $H$ is normal, then $n_2=1$, and I get the same problem as before. So $K=\{1\}$, and it's injective? Thanks.

Comment: @Tiffany: Indeed.

Comment: Great thank you. Thank you too @MarkDominus for the other approach.

Comment: You can also have $G$ act on the Sylow 2-subgroups by conjugation.

Comment: Related: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372455/a-non-abelian-group-of-order-6-is-isomorphic-to-s-3?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710524/if-g-is-non-abelian-group-of-order-6-it-is-isomorphic-to-s-3?rq=1)

Comment: @MJD Is it possible that your proof could be reduced by directly arguing that $G$ can be written as ${1, a, b, b^2, ab, ba}$ as no two elements are equal?

Comment: @fruitsauce To me that seems like exactly the same proof.

Comment: @MJD thanks, I was thinking there might be some flaw after seeing other solutions (which were not along these lines)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't talk about the quotient $G/H$ unless you first prove that $H$ is normal (which you won't be able to do, since a group of order $6$ always has a normal $3$-subgroup, and if it has a normal $2$-subgroup then it is abelian). If you are trying to talk about the cosets of $H$ in $G$, then the action by conjugation is not well-defined, since the coset $H$ is not mapped to a coset of $H$ under conjugation by any element not in $H$ (precisely because $H$ is not normal).

If you want to use actions, you *can* do it: let $H$ be a subgroup of order $2$ and consider the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ by left multiplication. This gives you a homomorphism $G\to S_3$; the kernel is contained in $H$, but since $H$ is of order $2$ and *not* normal, that means that the kernel is trivial, and so the map is an embedding. Since both $G$ and $S_3$ have order $6$, it follows that the map is an isomorphism.