# why $x^k \in x \langle y \rangle$ which does not contain $e$.?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A non-abelian group of order $ 6 $ is isomorphic to $ S_3 $

i have  taken  from

[A non-abelian group of order $ 6 $ is isomorphic to $ S_3 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372455/a-non-abelian-group-of-order-6-is-isomorphic-to-s-3)

as  i did n't undersatnds  the [image]  red line   not getting in my head

pliz help me,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $x^2=y^{-2}$, hence $x^2$ is generated by $y$ and hence $x^2 \in \langle y \rangle$. So if for example we assume $x^3=e$ then we get $e=x^3=xx^2 \in x\langle y \rangle$. But we have a problem here because the identity does not belong to any left coset of $\langle y \rangle$ which is not $\langle y \rangle$ itself. That is a contradiction. Same idea for $x^k$ with any odd $k$.

Comment: @ Mark.....one more  doubts    why identity  doesnot  belong  to  any  left  coset of <y> ??..

Comment: Let's assume it does belong to $x\langle y \rangle$. Then we have $e=xy^k$ for some k. Then we can multiply both sides by the inverse of $y^k$ and get $y^{-k}=x$ and hence $x \in \langle y \rangle$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks  u   @Mark.